# Website view showing inside bootstrap modal box in Codeigniter 3 during log out

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

In my web application, when I press log out then there is a bootstrap popup comes to ask about log out or not. Its working fine everywhere but not when the page is of edit. Means while edit page there is a parameter in address bar. **Due to that bootstrap modal box of log out showing entire website view inside modal box**. I am confused how's this possible. This is not the fault of codeigniter coding. Since, the page is working very fine.

On the same page if I remove the parameter from address bar then it works fine. Can't understand this weird error in codeigniter and bootstrap. Is there anyone here who faced same kind of issue before?

Image below of normal modal box that's how modal box should look and working on other pages.
[image]

Here below is the screenshot of the issue[image]

Comment: It might be wise and very helpful if you can submit some code in which the modal box is actioned etc.

Comment: Hi Jim, the code is actually working very fine. It's only making issue when the parameter is there in address bar. If I remove the parameter then this problem will not occur.

Comment: Likely suspect is that you're making an AJAX call and the code is wrong. You should share some of the code like Jim @said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was making a mistake. On log out link a href I was putting the link to and index.html page
like below

```
<li><a href="index.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a></li>
```

Then I removed the index.html link inside a tag. Now it's like below and the issue is resolved.

```
<li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a></li>
```